# Checkbox asp.net mvc selectlistitem from viewmodel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

net mvc and I'm trying to show the textbox and set the values from the  in the viewmodel. I wanted to get the value that the user will check from the list and store it in  *ActivityTypes2*. Im stuck with it and I'm not sure what approach to try.

**ViewModel**

```
public bool isCheckedActivityTypes2 { get; set; }
public string ActivityTypes2 { get; set; }
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActivityTypes2List
        {
            get
            {
                /*
                 TEA 2| TEA 3| TEA 4| TEA 5|*/
                return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = "TEA 2",
                        Text = "TEA 2"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = "TEA 3",
                        Text = "TEA 3"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = "TEA 4",
                        Text = "TEA 4"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value="TEA 5",
                        Text="TEA 5"
                    }
                };

            }
```

**New.cshtml**

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.isCheckedActivityTypes3, new { @style = "margin-right:10px" })<br />
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ActivityTypes3, Model.ActivityTypes3List)
```

Answer (score 2):

Define view model as follows :

```
public Testmodel()
        {
            ActivityTypes2List= ActivityTypesList.ToList();
        }           
        public List<SelectListItem> ActivityTypes2List { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActivityTypesList
        {
            get
            {
                /*
                 TEA 2| TEA 3| TEA 4| TEA 5|*/
                return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = "TEA 2",
                        Text = "TEA 2"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = "TEA 3",
                        Text = "TEA 3"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = "TEA 4",
                        Text = "TEA 4"
                    },
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value="TEA 5",
                        Text="TEA 5"
                    }
                };

            }
        }
```

Use following code in cshtml file

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ActivityTypes2List.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ActivityTypes2List[i].Selected)

            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ActivityTypes2List[i].Text)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityTypes2List[i].Value)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityTypes2List[i].Text)
        }
```

And while getting it in controller use following code in Post method which will give you selected values:

```
var selected = model.ActivityTypes2List.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```